# Fabric.io - Answers - Filter and sum data by range?

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics, fabric.io

I've been using Answers and Crashlytics by Fabric in my iOS application (Swift) to track use behavior. I setup a custom event so that whenever someone clicks on a tab, it logs the event.

..The problem is in the Answers user interface, it tells me the breakdown by each day but doesn't let me aggregate over a date range.

If my users can click on 4 tabs, and i'm logging each one with a custom event with a custom key, all I want to do is:

For the entire year, or some date range, show me a breakdown of each tab tapped (so i'd like to see tab 1: 30 people tapped, tab 2: 20 people tapped, etc.). It doesn't seem like Answers lets you change/filter date ranges.

Any ideas? Maybe you all know of some better tool to track application analytics that's good for iOS? I don't like App Insights by Microsoft.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find solution? I have the same issue. I also can recommend to try Flurry. It tracks data for whole period of time, not just "Today". It's free as well. But it's not real time. So you have to wait 12-24 hours to see data.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way around this, with the only app changes being ones you'll have to make in the next few months anyway.

1. [Migrate your project to Firebase](https://fabric.io/blog/the-future-of-fabric/) (which you'll have to do soon anyway).
2. [Connect your Firebase project to Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery).
3. Your Analytics data is now available in a SQL-style database.

From there, you can fine tune a SQL query ([full table schema](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9036484)) to pull out whatever data you want. [There are examples available](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery#working_with_firebase_crashlytics_data_in_bigquery), but if you do go down this path I suggest you ask a new question to fine tune the query. It will be something like this modified version of [example #2](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-bigquery#querying_a_custom_event_parameter):

```
SELECT COUNT(event_dim.name) as TabClicks,
    event_dim.params.value.string_value as TabName
FROM com.example.myapp.app_events_
WHERE event_dim.params.key = 'tabClicked'
GROUP BY TabName
ORDER BY TabName ASC
```